# How to use the signed apk file on phone?

Tags: debugging, android-studio, apk, release, signed-apk

Using the Android Studio I was able to build my app.
After building I navigated to Build Variant changed to release.
Then using the Generate Signed Apk got the apk file: `app-release.apk`

Before uploading this file on phone I wanted to use this in my emulator and see if it's working. I navigated to the platform-tools directory and tried to use this command: `adb install app-release.apk`

But I am getting this error:

> Failure:[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

Comment: Is the application already installed on the device ? If so, just uninstall it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It is already installed. Try Unstalling old first and install this new one.

The solution is open a command prompt and type:

```
adb uninstall package-name
```

than

```
adb install app-release.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a version higher of app in your device, please first uninstall it. after run again